# How to move table row's data in a td to upwards td if td is empty

Tags: css, html-table

I have one html table and there are some rows inside the table. See the code below-

```
       <table border="1">

          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td></td>!-- Empty row -->
            <td>Column 4</td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
         </tr>    

      </table>
```

And it will looks like below in browser-

[image]

We can see in above html code that, there is an empty "td" in first row. And it's showing blank when we are running the code in browser. I just want to move the data in each td to upwards td if there is no data in it.

So that, it should looks like below-

[image]

Is there any way to handle this by **CSS** changes ? If not then by any **HTML** changes. But I would like to avoid using any third party JS/CSS file to handle this.

Comment: You must use javascript for this problem.

Comment: What would be the _point_ of this? If your column content can "move" to a different row so willy-nilly - then it is hard to imagine that what you have there actually makes much sense as table data in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the data is columnar: an item is not related to items on its left and right but to items above and below it. In that case you *should* change the HTML markup:

```css
#data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#data > div > div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

#data > div > div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="data">
  <div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><!-- empty --></div>
    <div>Column 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Column 4</div>
    <div>Column 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example, uses semantic markup and css grid to align cells nicely:

```css
/* reset */
dl {
  margin: 0;
}
dt {
  background-color: orange;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
/* grid layout */
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: .5em;
}
dt:nth-of-type(2),
dt:nth-of-type(2) ~ dd {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
dt:nth-of-type(3),
dt:nth-of-type(3) ~ dd {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
dt:nth-of-type(4),
dt:nth-of-type(4) ~ dd {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}
dd:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Heading 1</dt>
  <dd>Value 1<br>another line</dd>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
  <dt>Heading 2</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
  <dt>Heading 3</dt>
  <dd><!-- empty --></dd>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
  <dt>Heading 4</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: #Salman A, this fix is working fine. But there is one issue if any dd/cell is having an empty value then widths are not showing correctly for dd's. It's showing less width for empty dd and for some dd's widths are increasing. But I need to show equal width's for dd's whether its empty or not empty.

Comment: widths? do you mean height? can you post a fiddle?

Comment: #Salman A, actually whatever width I am giving for my "dd" elements its not reflecting in PDF. It's working fine in html but when we are saving the html into pdf its not taking that width.

Comment: That is a different question, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Comment: #salman A, for my above comment I raise new question. Please have a look-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76439091/html-dd-empty-cell-is-not-taking-the-equal-space/76439544?noredirect=1#comment134784601_76439544